Is it legal for a feeder to pass through a subpanel in a different housing unit?
I recently asked a question about my replacing my old 'stab-lok' subpanel, but I have another question on a different prickly issue I'm facing on the same panel.  After close inspection I see the upstairs neighbor's main feed is going through my panel!  The conduit that's bringing my main feed from subfloor also contains the upstairs unit's feed (two black and one white #8 wires). You can see them in the upper right corner of the panel.
In the diagram, I've drawn them in red.  Also, one of the hot wires is cut and reconnected by a nut (upper left), but the neutral and the other hot wire just pass through my sub panel.
Question 1:  Is this even up to code?
Question 2:  since I was planning to remove and replace this old  subpanel, what should I do with the neighbor's line?




If you have that panel, 90% plus your neighbour has also, and might not know of the danger.  It would be nice to let them know.  Panel boxes can be used as junction(wire splices) boxes.  Not sure, but the owner of the building might be responsible for the costs.

I take it your electricity is fed in on separate hot and neutral wires from your upstairs neighbor's?

Do you both have separate meters?

Yes, separate wires and separate meters.  meters and main disconnect are outside in the common area.  Each unit is individually owned.

@Ari -- who is your electric utility?

LADWP,  why?

@Ari -- just making sure they don't have rules about this situation

Since you are on separate meters this raises a few issues:

Junction Box

This is the easy part. Assuming you plan to put a new panel in this location, I would put in a separate junction box (doesn't have to be very big for 8 AWG wires) next to it (above, below, left, right, surface mount, whatever works). Actually, you may need two junction boxes, depending on how much slack is in the wires. If there is enough slack to split the neutral and unbroken hot and wire together in another box (and move the already split hot as well), great. If there isn't enough slack then you'll need one box at the top (doesn't have to be literally the top, could be near the top off to one side, etc. - whatever works) and one at the bottom and a length of conduit in between and join one set of wires (the already split hot and the to-be-split hot and neutral) in the top box, run 8 AWG matching wires through the conduit to the bottom box and connect them to the other set of wires. A little bit of extra work but if you do this before everything else then it won't take long and you'll have the panel fully available to replace it.

Wires In Conduit

This is a bit of an unknown to me. Need a code expert to give a definitive answer. The question is whether you can have multiple circuits from different meters in the same conduit. If you can, or if it is ambiguous enough that the inspector will let you do it, great - leave it as is. If you used to be allowed (this may be, like so many other things, something that changed over the years) then it should be grandfathered. But if you can't then this is a real issue because you would need to not only deal with the junction box but also add new conduit (or cable if allowed) going all the way from this panel to the meter/main feed.

Wire Size

8 AWG wires (not cable) can handle up to 50A. If the neighbor decides to replace their panel then they will likely end up with a higher capacity panel - even the smallest subpanels typically start at 60A. Which means it is absolutely critical to make sure that the feed breaker (likely at or near the meter but we really don't know) is 50A, or this may be the time to upgrade the wires. But if the wires are going to be upgraded then that involves the lower section and the upper section. In fact, if the wires are upgraded then you may be able to put in junction boxes/conduit bodies in a way new wires can be fed all the way through without any cuts/connections which will make things easier all around. Which means figuring that out before messing around with junction boxes as described above.

Would it be possible to keep that box(with the insides removed) for the neighbour's wires, and move all of OP's wires to the new box?

@crip659 Absolutely. (Pending the issue of shared conduit.) But keep in mind that while a junction box can go anywhere accessible (floor, ceiling, anywhere that isn't physically blocked) a panel has very specific requires (30" x 36" in front of it, I am pretty sure minimum and maximum distance from floor, etc.) and having to move or extend one circuit (neighbor's) is a lot easier than having to move or extend half the circuits in a panel.

All the units are under supplied in my opinion.  My own small unit's feed is only 30A while the upstairs unit is 40A.   Never had any issues but I was thinking of upgrading to 50A with new #6 wires.  The main panel has a label saying max 50A per branch circuit.

The fact that the smallest of subpanels available today typically has 60A capacity isn't relevant to the feeder wire sizing: they could replace with a 200A-rated subpanel and that would be fine. Feeder size is based on a load calculation; the buss bar rating of the fed panel may be anything equal to or greater than the calculation. An alternative, in case it's more appealing, to the top/2nd j-box and length of wire solution would be to use a longer length of new wire which reaches from bottom/1st j-box all the way to neighbor's panel.

@Ari Your choices are to leave them inside the replaced panel or run them through new conduit or new boxes + conduit. Individual wires can't just be inside the wall unprotected. Any of these options would mean either cutting and rejoining the 2 out of 3 that are currently continuous - or alternatively temporarily disconnecting at one end (meter/main or neighbor's panel) because otherwise you can't do the work of pulling out the old panel and putting in a new one, unless you find a panel that lets you replace the guts without replacing the box.

Thanks.  I tore some drywall, and now I see I don't have enough space for a new panel wider than 12-13"!  there are two 3x4s 13" apart plus a 1" conduit (added a new pic).  Now I have a new problem that I can't find any panels that wide.  anyone knows of one?

Put a piece of plywood on there. Install a surface mount panel. (Pretty much all can be mounted flush or on the surface) Drill holes for the conduit to get through and, depending on location, bring the conduit to top, bottom, left, right or back of the new panel.

I'd rather not do a surface mount because the panel is in the bedroom by the door, but as a last resort I might have to.  So far I found two 'renovation' panels that might work:  Eaton BR1020H100FRNWV and Siemens E1020MB1100FCGP.
